# Laravel what does the session table column "payload" contain, and how can I access this data?

Tags: php, laravel, session

I grabbed the only value from my sessions table locally, it is me I'm the only logged in user.

```
$data = DB::table('sessions')->get();
```

If I return the base64_decoded payload:

```
    return  base64_decode($data[0]->payload);
```

I get what looks like encrypted json.

```
a:5:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"IlIvr7p3qxeMRg0NxSaITHvIZ1c2HGCh5QSj8wIG";s:9:"_previous";a:1:{s:3:"url";s:28:"http://mytestsite.dev/index.php";}s:5:"flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}s:8:"class_id";s:2:"14";s:9:"_sf2_meta";a:3:{s:1:"u";i:1453341204;s:1:"c";i:1453331047;s:1:"l";s:1:"0";}}
```

Is there a secure way to decrypt this JSON to retrieve the user id using Laravels methods?

Upon further investigation it may be that the session table does not contain the user info, it is just used to match with the browser cookie?

If this is the case, my ultimate question is how can I reasonably determine which users are currently logged in without creating update/inserts on the user record constantly on every page load, as suggested here: [Can someone explain session table laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17051304/can-someone-explain-session-table-laravel?rq=1)

_________________________UPDATE

Ok from my further research I found that the cookie in the browser is the encrypted id of the session record.

```
        return Crypt::decrypt($cookie);
```

This leaves one final question, what does the payload column contain?

Comment: [That's not JSON](http://json.org/). It seems to be [UBJSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBJSON).

Comment: "I get what looks like encrypted json."

Comment: Is the user id which you are trying to receive anywhere in the UBJSON data you provided?

Comment: I believe so, along with other data. Seems it would require a reverse engineering of the Authetication process. I found this, but I think it is out dated. https://labs.mwrinfosecurity.com/blog/2014/04/11/laravel-cookie-forgery-decryption-and-rce/

Comment: To clarify: what data inside the example is the value you are trying to get? Is it included literally? encrypted? Can you use `Auth::user()->id` or `Auth::id()`?

Comment: No, I want to grab all records in the session table that were created within the last 15 minutes, and then find out the user's ids. This way I can see how many users are logged in at the moment.

Comment: Why not just add a column to the user table of `logged_in_at` and update it every time a user logs in?

Comment: Did that, added events for login and logout. The only thing with that is we have "stay logged in" option which most user opt for. We see their original login but are not sure if they are "currently logged in" as in actively viewing the site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this after you have the payload it will show you json object.

```
print_r(unserialize(base64_decode($datas->payload))); 
dd(unserialize(base64_decode($datas->payload)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so looks like Laravel 5.2 has this issue fixed.

```
Schema::create('sessions', function ($table) {
    $table->string('id')->unique();
    $table->integer('user_id')->nullable();
    $table->string('ip_address', 45)->nullable();
    $table->text('user_agent')->nullable();
    $table->text('payload');
    $table->integer('last_activity');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In **laravel 5.7**
We can access payload data by

```
$actual = decrypt(base64_decode($payload));
```

where **$payload** is the value of "payload" column in "sessions" table in DB.

I assume you use

```
SESSION_DRIVER=database
```